# Regular expression including wildcard character in search string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression for a string
This string can contain `*` and `?` in it. But should have at least 3 alphanumeric character in it.
So,

```
*abc* is valid
*ab*c is valid
*aaa? is valid
*aa  is not valid
**aaa is not valid as it is not a valid regular expression
```

Comment: So do you want a regular expression for a regular expression or what you described? Because your last comment '**aaa is not valid as it is not a valid regular expression' doesn't line up with '*abc* is valid'.

Comment: I mean *aaa is valid while **aaa(2 continuous astrixs) is not valid, as we even don't write this kind of string in regular expression also.

Comment: So how is `*abc*` a valid regex, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^[*?]?([0-9a-z][*?]?){3,}$
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string
- `[*?]?` matches an optional `*` or `?`
- `(...){3,}` the group must appear at least 3 times
- `[0-9a-z][*?]?` matches an alphanumeric character followed by an optional `*` or `?`
- `$` matches the end of the string

Consecutive `*` and `?`  are not matched.

**Update:** Forgot to mention it, but it was on my mind: Use `i` modifier to make the match case-insensitive (`/.../i`).

Comment: @polishchuk: As far as I understood it, consecutive wildcards are not valid. So this is intended.

Comment: this regular expression is working for me. Don't know why this question got negative, may be because I was not able to explain it properly. Thanks for understanding it well.

Comment: @Nits: It was probably wrong to name your input a regular expression. It is more like you wrote in the title, placeholders. But anyway, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

can use regex and implment it in javascript

```
var searchin = item.toLowerCase();
var str = "*abc*";
str = str.replace(/[*]/g, ".*").toLowerCase().trim();
return new RegExp("^"+ str + "$").test(searchin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm guessing that `?` represents any one character and `*` any number of characters, and that you want to disallow consecutive `*`, but not consecutive `?` (so that `file.???` would be valid, representing `file.` followed by three chars, eg `file.txt`), and allow other content than just `[A-Za-z\d*?]`:

```
/^(?!.*\*\*)(?:[^a-z\d]*[a-z\d]){3,}[^a-z\d]*/i
```

Assuming that `file.???*` should be valid too, since this combination means "at least 3 chars".